# How do I turn a string reference into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want `$masking_x` to act as `$masking_y` (i.e. dynamically insert `$radiovalue` but still act as a varibale).

My code is

```
while($field_radio = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_radio)) {
    $radiovalue = $field_radio[radiovalue];
    echo "Radio value: ".$radiovalue."</br>";   
    $masking = "field_masking[checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue."]";
    $masking_x = '$'.$masking;
    $masking_y = "$field_masking[checkbox_1001_2]";
    echo "Masking: ".$masking."</br>";
    echo "Masking_x: ".$masking_x."</br>";
    echo "Masking_y: ".$masking_y."</br>";
    die;
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Radio value: 2
Masking: field_masking[checkbox_1001_2]
Masking_x: $field_masking[checkbox_1001_2]
Masking_y: 2
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Does `field_masking` have to be dynamic as well? What's wrong with `echo $field_masking["checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically access an array variable, split it in two parts, single variable won't work.

```
$name = 'field_masking';
$key = 'checkbox_1001_'.$radiovalue;

echo $$name[$key];
```

Comment: Thank you; The field_masking did not have to be dynamic so Naltharial's $field_masking["checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue]; solution solved my problem.  I also learned quite a bit from the other comments and I'm gratefully for everyone's help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) slightly wrong. Try this instead:

```
$radiovalue = $field_radio['radiovalue'];
echo "Radio value: ".$radiovalue."</br>";   
$masking_x = "field_masking['checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue."']";
$masking_y = "field_masking['checkbox_1001_2']";
echo "Masking_x: ".$$masking_x."</br>";
echo "Masking_y: ".$$masking_y."</br>";
```

The double dollar-sign must be in the code, not in the string.

It's also possible to do this:

```
$radiovalue = $field_radio['radiovalue'];
echo "Radio value: ".$radiovalue."</br>";   
echo "Masking_x: ".${"field_masking['checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue."']"}."</br>";
echo "Masking_y: ".${"field_masking['checkbox_1001_2']"}."</br>";
```

Note also that I added single quotes into your string to properly quote the strings used for the array keys, associative array keys these are regular strings and should be quoted as such.

**However** it is important to note that variable variables are rarely the right solution to a given problem. It's usually possible to come up with something better using [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) or [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) instead.

**EDIT**

After playing around with it, it seems you cannot use a variable variable to reference an array key when the key definition is in the string. It's such a horrible thing to do, I'm not surprised I've never come across this limitation.

The long of the short of it is that you cannot do exactly what you are trying to do, and the best solution for you is probably to use references instead:

```
$radiovalue = $field_radio['radiovalue'];
echo "Radio value: ".$radiovalue."</br>";   
$masking = &$field_masking['checkbox_1001_'.$radiovalue];
echo "Masking: ".$masking."</br>";
$masking = "A different value";
echo "Masking: ".$masking."</br>";
// Original value has been updated as well
echo "\$field_masking['checkbox_1001_'.\$radiovalue]: ".$field_masking['checkbox_1001_'.$radiovalue]."</br>";
```

Comment: I get undefined errors on all of those. What PHP version supports that?

Comment: @Naltharial After playing around with it, it seems you cannot use a variable variable to reference an array key when the key definition is in the string. It's such a horrible thing to do, I'm not surprised I've never come across this limitation. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you; The field_masking did not have to be dynamic so Naltharial's $field_masking["checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue]; solution solved my problem.  I also learned quite a bit from the other comments and I'm gratefully for everyone's help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Do note that this is a potential security risk if you're working with user input.

In your case: `$masking_x = $$masking;`

Comment: Thank you; The field_masking did not have to be dynamic so Naltharial's $field_masking["checkbox_1001_".$radiovalue]; solution solved my problem.  I also learned quite a bit from the other comments and I'm gratefully for everyone's help. Thanks again.